# Any of the properties equals any of a list of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem in Entity-Framework, using Code-First, that I couldn't solve.

Having entities of the type

```
public class Product {
  public int ID {get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category {
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
  // rest omitted
}
```

in my database, i try to get all Products that have at least one Category from a list of given Categories. I need an Expression as this expression is combined with other expressions later.

Ie.  i tried:

```
var searchFor = new List<Category>{...};
var expression = product => product.Categories.Any(cat => searchFor.Contains(cat))
```

Executing this later against a `DbContext`

```
context.Products.Where(expression).ToList();
```

creates an exception stating mainly that `This context supports primitive types only`.

Changing it to

```
var expression = product => product.Categories.Any(
                              cat => searchFor.Any(d => d.ID == cat.ID));
```

to get rid of the object comparison didn't help. I'm stuck. How can I manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already got a list of categories, you can build a list of IDs *outside* the query:

```
var searchForIds = searchFor.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
var query = context.Products
                   .Where(product => product.Categories
                                     .Any(cat => searchForIds.Contains(cat.ID)));
```

I don't *know* that that will work, but it might. (Apologies for the indentation... it's just to avoid scrolling.)

Answer (score 2):

You should get rid of `List<Category>`, replacing it with a list of IDs, like this:

```
// I'm assuming that ID is of type long; please fix as necessary
var searchFor = new List<long>{...};
var expression = product =>
    product.Categories.Any(cat => searchFor.Contains(cat.ID))
```